# Longest sequence of words with no repeating letters

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sequence

I have a list of words. I need to choose the longest sequence of them with no repeating letters. For example, my words are:

```
ab
cd
cxyz
```

The longest sequence is (6 letters):

```
ab-cxyz
```

The order is not imoratant. I am looking for an efficient way of choosing such a sequence (list of 1000 words at least).

I tried to adapt the solution of [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) for this one but it gave the wrong result.

Comment: I don't understand how you find **ab-cxyz**. Shouldn't **d** replace **-**?

Comment: @Fumidu He cannot put d, because it requires to put `cd`, and `c` already appears in `cxyz` - he needs to choose cxyz OR cd, can't have them both.

Comment: Not sure, but it smells NP-Hardish  to me, and a variation of Set Cover

Comment: @amit it actually is [weighted set packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing#Weighted_version), with the word lengths as weigths, which is indeed NP-hard. I can't find a good reference though.

Comment: http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node144.html But I suppose that OP knows that it has no polynomial time solution, and still wants to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a graph like this: for each word you create a node and you connect two words with an edge if they have a common letter. You also assign a weight to each node, which is word's length. You are now searching for an independent set of nodes, e.g a set of words with no edge between them. You also need this independent set to have a maximum weight.

This is an instance of [maximum weight independent set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29) and it's unfortunately a NP-hard problem without any known good approximation algorithms.